# Do I need a calendar to join tables in access and report by month

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join, outer-join

I have to 3 tables that I need to join in Access. So I have created queries to obtain the "Team" field with an inner join [Table A] to [Table C] on "Assoc. NO" and then another one on [Table B] to [Table C] also on "Assoc. NO].

**MY ISSUE**

I use a query based on [Table C] and [Table A] to obtain the months, but then I am missing months if they did not exist in [Table A] and only [Table B]. Do I need to create a table that only has months and years and create a join to that? I apologize for the long post but want to provide as much info as possible. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Table A
|Name         | Assoc. NO |month|Year|Product|SaleA|
|John Smith   |   1       |Jan  |2016|Apple  |$10 |
|John Smith   |   1       |Jan  |2016|Pear   |$5  |
|John Smith   |   1       |Feb  |2016|Apple  |$10 |
|George Martin|   2       |Feb  |2016|Apple  |$10 |
|George Martin|   2       |Feb  |2016|Apple  |$10 |
|George Martin|   2       |Feb  |2016|Pear   |$5  |


Table B
|Name         | Assoc. NO |month|Year|Service   |SaleB|
|John Smith   |   1       |Jan  |2016|oil change|$25  |
|George Martin|   2       |Jan  |2016|oil change|$25  |
|Mark James   |   3       |Feb  |2016|oil change|$25  |
|Mark James   |   3       |Mar  |2016|oil change|$25  |
|George Martin|   2       |Mar  |2016|oil change|$25  |

Table C
|Team   |Name         | Assoc. NO |
|Team A |John Smith   |   1       |
|Team B |George Martin|   2       |
|Team B |Mark James   |   3       |
```

What I would Like to see is the following:

```
Query 
|Team   |Name         | Month  |Sale |SaleB|SUM(SaleA,SaleB)|
|-------|-------------|--------|-----|-----|----------------|
|Team A |John Smith   |   Jan  | $15 | $25 |  $40           |
|Team A |John Smith   |   Feb  | $10 | $0  |  $10           |
|Team B |George Martin|   Jan  | $0  | $25 |  $25           |
|Team B |George Martin|   Feb  | $25 | $0  |  $25           |
|Team B |George Martin|   Mar  | $0  | $25 |  $25           |
|Team C |Mark James   |   Feb  | $0  | $25 |  $25           |
|Team C |Mark James   |   Feb  | $0  | $25 |  $25           |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT [Table C].Team, [Table C].Name, [Table C].[Assoc No], Month, Sum(T.SaleA) AS TotA, Sum(T.SaleB) AS TotB, [TotA]+[TotB] AS Total
FROM

(select [Assoc no], Month, SaleA, 0 as SaleB from [Table A] 
UNION ALL select [Assoc No], Month, 0, Saleb from [Table B])  AS T

INNER JOIN [Table C] ON T.[Assoc No]= [Table C].[Assoc No]
GROUP BY [Table C].Team, [Table C].Name, Table C].[Assoc No], T.Month;
```

Comment: Are you referring to Table C.Team or Query C. Team and so on?

Comment: all the references to A, B and C are to the tables that you defined in the question.

Comment: I am getting a pop up "Enter Parameter Value" "SaleB"

Comment: I edited the answer to use your table names - see if that helps.  It worked fine when I modelled it in my own DB.  Are SaleA and SaleB the proper names for the fields in tables A and B?

Comment: Don, Is it possible to add data from two more tables via the Union?

Comment: Yes - I've used unions of at least 12 tables, and I don't know if there is a limit or not.  Just add more "UNION ALL Select ..." items inside the ().  Each item included has to have has to have the same number of columns in the same order.  You can also move the union to it's own query and use that query to build the next one that summarizes the data from the union.